# Do electron (or other quantum particles) move in a 4th spatial dimension?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, orbitals

I was told that an electron can change its position from position A to position B without appearing  anywhere between A and B.

So i think that it might be possible for an electron to move in 4D or other Dimensions.
This can be further using real example. Suppose a satellite which can click photos only in 2D tries to capture motion person who is standing on roof of building.Someone observing via satellite might expect that that person should have straight line path for his movement from point X to Y but a 3D human uses staircases (to move in third dimension) to arrive at point Y. So his 3d motion will go undetected by 2d satellite and person will seem to teleport from X to Y.

So that way we might too not be able to understand 4d motion of electron due to our limitation of understanding in that dimension.

Question is **Am I correct?**

Comment: So all measuring devices interact with the fourth dimension and can pull the electron from anywhere in back into the plane we exist in?

Comment: I think that the first sentence here is slightly suspect. I don't think it would happen if one were to continuously measure each location between $A$ and $B$ for the presence of an electron (think about bubble chambers for example).

Comment: @BioPhysicist sorry i didn't thought that way

Comment: *Am I correct?* Personal theories are off-topic on this site.

Comment: This great answer by knzhou may be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/488540/123208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is sound evidence that no fourth physical dimension exists in this way.

If it did, stuff would linger in there and many conservation laws, of mass, energy, charge, etc. would appear to be violated in our 3D world.

Also, the jump of say an electron is thought to be instantaneous. There is no measurable time delay. If a classical particle were to travel across in any physical dimension it would have to go faster than light, which would violate Relativity.

There is also a problem with what that "particle" really is. Any ideas of a "local, real" particle are ruled out by a mass of experimental evidence. According to the standard theory, what actually crosses the gap is the probability of finding the electron when we look for it. The probability distribution is modelled by a wave equation, which straddles the gap. To dig any deeper is to turn metaphysical and make untestable statements.

Some theories, such as Kaluza-Klein, string and M theories do postulate more dimensions, but (with one exception) nothing ever leaves ours, objects just extend across all of them.

That exception is based on highly speculative Multiverse theories where our universe is one of many floating in a higher-dimensional plenum. It has been suggested that gravitons could be able to leak out into the higher-dimensional plenum and this is why gravity is such a weak force in its native space. But such speculations have huge problems to overcome - why then do we not feel gravity from other universes, why only gravitons, why some and not others, and so on.