# How Quickly Does an Atom Transfer From One Orbital to Another?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, half-life

Here's the research that I've done:

- The Schrödinger equation:
  $$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(t)\rangle=\hat{H}|\psi(t)\rangle$$
  Ok, it evolves as a function of time. That tells us something.
- An image containing (possibly) 2-D slices of the atomic orbitals of the hydrogen atom:
  [image]
  <sub>(image from [Wikimedia: Hydrogen density plots](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png))</sub>
  And I don't see a time variable in the equation above.

**How fast (in seconds) does an orbital transfer from one configuration to another configuration?**

Comment: It depends on the atom, on the orbital, and on the process causing the transfer. I suggest asking a more precise question.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/488527/123208

Comment: The formula for $\psi$ in the image deliberately omits the factor $e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$. This factor doesn't matter when calculating $|\psi|^2$ for the density plots.